# Hadoop Java Word Count tweak not working - try to sum all

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count

I'm trying to tweak the wordcount example found here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount so it will sum and return the number of words in the input file instead of counting the occurrences of each word.

I tried changing the mapper class in a way that instead of writing the word in the current iteration, it will write "Sum: " for all words.

i.e. replace

```
 word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

@class "Map" with

```
 word.set("Sum: ");
```

All the rest of the file remains the same.

In that way I thought all mappers output get to the same reducer that will eventually sum the number of "sum: "'s which will eventually be the number of words in the file.

meaning instead of:

```
 word  1
 other 1
 other 1
```

that yields:

```
word  1
other 2
```

I was expecting to have:

```
 Sum:  1
 Sum:  1
 Sum:  1
```

that yields:

```
 Sum: 3
```

Instead, when I try and run the code, I get a really long mapping operation that eventually end up with an exeption thrown:

**RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Spill failed**

no matter how small the input file is.

Looking forward for your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an endless loop. In your code, you need to call

```
tokenizer.nextToken()
```

to actually advance the StringTokenizer by a word from the line. Otherwise your mapping operation will never make progress.

So you would need something like this:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text sumText = new Text("Sum: ");
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokenizer.nextToken(); //go to next word
            context.write(sumText, one);
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a better solution without a loop. You can use ẗhe [`countTokens()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens()) method of StringTokenizer:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        context.write(new Text("Sum: "), new IntWritable(tokenizer.countTokens()));
    }
}
```